# How to permanently disable a view in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working over a standalone Eclipse-RCP application, backed by EJB3.0 and it has a `Show View` window where you can select what view to open. There's some options as `Console` and `Navigator` that I don't want to show to the final user. The original developers are unreachable.

So far every new window/view I used I could press `f9` (plug-in selection spy) over the window/view and I could get the name of class used to create that window/view. Although I used this on `Console` view, with `ctrl+shift+R` I can't get any class named ConseleView from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView`

Here's the info I can get with `f9`:

[image]

Is there more than one place to set this option? If no, where should I look? XML configuration files? Database? I know anybody can solve a problem without seen the full application's code. But there's a specific place to start looking for?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are asking. `org.eclipse.ui.internal.console.ConsoleView` is the class that implements the console view.

Comment: I asking if is it possible to completely deny access to this class from user interface and if there's a single way to do this.

Comment: You might be able to use [Eclipse Activities](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_advext_activities.htm) to hide the various menu items that show this view.